# About character encode with PortableAllegroServe

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, common-lisp, httpserver

I'm using sbcl(1.1.15) on archlinux and PortableAserve to write a web application. But I have some troubles when I using the character like "测试".

The REPL print the error only:got error The value 30334 is not of type (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8).
And the browser show nothing.

Here is my code:

```
(defpackage #:com.web
  (:use :common-lisp :net.aserve))

(in-package :com.web)

(defun test-character-encode (req ent)
  (with-http-response (req ent :content-type "text/html")
    (with-http-body (req ent)
      (format
        (request-reply-stream req)
        "测试portableallegroserve"))))

(publish :path "/test" :function 'test-character-encode)
```

How can I do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `with-http-body` describes an `:external-format` argument which may be what you need to specify:

> ```
> (with-http-body (req ent &key format headers external-format)  &rest body)
> ```
>
> Within the body forms the code calls (request-reply-stream req) to
>   obtain a stream to which it can write to supply the body of the
>   response.   **The external-format of this stream is set to the value of
>   the external-format argument (which defaults to the value of
>   *default-aserve-external-format*).**   The variable *html-stream* is bound to the value of (request-reply-stream req) before the body is
>   evaluated.   This makes it easy  to use the html macro to generate
>   html as part of the response.

Based on this, perhaps you need something like

```
(with-http-body (req ent :external-format :utf-8) 
  (format
    (request-reply-stream req)
    "测试portableallegroserve"))))
```

Comment: If this works, don't forget to set the Content-Type accordingly: `:content-type "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: It don't work and REPL print the same error msg. I visit localhost at port 1234 by using (net.aserve.client:do-http-request "http://127.0.0.1:1234/test"). It show me the error message:Unexpected end-of-file while reading chunk block
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Comment: Did you also add the content-type: header as another comment suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did the keywords: :content-type "text/html;charset=UTF-8". If I format the string "abc测试def" to browser, only "abc" can be showd before the chinese character.